# PySimpleGUI loop need better way

Tags: python, loops, pysimplegui

I tried a to loop some elements in PySimpleGUI using PySimpleGUIQt
here's the code:

```
list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

layout = [[Sg.Column([[Sg.Input(do_not_clear=True, size=(20, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'G_INPUT0{j}'), Sg.Column([[Sg.Input(do_not_clear=True, size=(14, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'INPUT{i}{j}') for i in range(9)]])],[Sg.Listbox(list_1, size=(20, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'G_LIST0{j}'), Sg.Column([[Sg.Listbox(list_1, size=(14, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'LIST{i}{j}')for i in range(9)]])],[Sg.Text(' G: ', size=(20, 0.7), key=f'G_TEXT{j}'), Sg.Column([[Sg.Text(f' T{i}: ', size=(14, 0.7), key=f'TEXT{i}{j}')for i in range(9)]])]])]for j in range(3)]
window = Sg.Window('Sample GUI', layout, finalize=True)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    print(event)
    print(values)
```

Output: [image]
The issue is if I want to add new loop I need to add `Sg.Column` which makes extra space, and add one more loop but I don't wanna use `Sg.Column` so can anyone tell me a fix where I can get get similar to this result [image] **made using ms paint**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code without any `sg.Column`

```py
import PySimpleGUIQt as Sg

list_1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

layout = []

for j in range(3):
    layout += [
        [Sg.Checkbox("Some text", pad=(3, 20))],
        [Sg.Input(do_not_clear=True, size=(20, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'G_INPUT0{j}')] +
        [Sg.Input(do_not_clear=True, size=(14, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'INPUT{i}{j}') for i in range(9)],
        [Sg.Listbox(list_1, size=(20, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'G_LIST0{j}')] +
        [Sg.Listbox(list_1, size=(14, 0.7), enable_events=True, key=f'LIST{i}{j}') for i in range(9)],
        [Sg.Text(' G: ', size=(20, 0.7), key=f'G_TEXT{j}')] +
        [Sg.Text(f' T{i}: ', size=(14, 0.7), key=f'TEXT{i}{j}') for i in range(9)]
    ]

window = Sg.Window('Sample GUI', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == Sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldn't figure out a way to how to add `+` .

Comment: use `+` to join two list to as one row, maybe one of lists generated by list comprehension.

Comment: The Demo Program `Demo_Layout_Generation.py` shows the ways that you can use the `+` operator with layouts to make all kinds of these combined layouts that use list comprehensions and loops. Really handy operations like in Jason's example. The documentation has a section about them too that you might like. https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#generated-layouts-for-sure-want-to-read-if-you-have-5-repeating-elementsrows